# Why would uploading a zip file via ftp_fput return true but not upload the file?

Tags: php, xml, ftp

The following command returns true and uploads the text XML file to the FTP server:

```
if (ftp_put($this->ftpConnectionId, $this->remoteXmlFileName, $this->localXmlFileName, FTP_ASCII)) {
```

However, when I try to upload a .zip file intead of a text XML file, it still returns true but does not upload the file:

```
if (ftp_put($this->ftpConnectionId, $this->remoteXmlFileName, $this->localXmlFileName, FTP_BINARY)) {
```

I found that if I simply rename the zip file to ".xml", it WILL upload the file but the .zip file is corrupted.

But if I rename the zip file to ".zip.xml" it again returns true but does not upload the file.

**What could be the reasons for this odd behavior?**

### Additional Info:

A zip file can be uploaded via FileZilla no problem with the same account.

I also am specifing:

```
ftp_pasv($this->ftpConnectionId, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A zipfile is a binary file. That's probably why uploading it as .xml corrupts the file. Try specifying FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII. FTP_BINARY will work for ascii files too, but not vice versa, so you can better always use FTP_BINARY than always FTP_ASCII.

The ftp server may reject the file for many reasons, so it may allow the upload at first, but then not save the file. The ascii/binary problem may be one, but also some file extensions may be blacklisted, or the file could be too big. The latter is unlikely, though, since uploading the zipfile with a different extensions worked for you.

I think the ftp server actively ignores zip files.

Comment: sorry, I copied that in wrong: I am using FTP_BINARY with the binary zip file, corrected above

Comment: What if you try a different extension, for instance .bin instead of .xml? Maybe the transfer encoding is implicitly changed back to ASCII because of the .xml extension.

Comment: But uploading zip files manually with FileZilla works, and I see in its log that it sets TYPE I (which is what I do with FTP_BINARY) and it also sets PASV which I also do with ftp_pasv.

Comment: Doesn't the FTP server keep a log? This way it's just guessing, but a log will probably tell you more.

Comment: thanks, asking for and checking the log eventually solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is because zip file contains Files and may be is size is greater than your XMl

We have used this code to upload entire directory over ftp

Try this code. This will work for your ftp

```
//Start ftp upload code
    $ftp_user_name =$_SESSION['upload']['username'];
    $ftp_user_pass = $_SESSION['upload']['password'];
    $ftp_server = $_SESSION['upload']['host'];
    $sourcepath = $_SESSION['upload']['source'];
    $dest_folder = $_SESSION['upload']['dest_folder'];          
    $conn_id = @ftp_connect($ftp_server,21) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
    if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
        ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 70000000000000000); // Set the network timeout to 10 seconds
        ftp_copyAll($conn_id, $sourcepath, $dest_folder);

       }


      function ftp_copyAll($conn_id, $src_dir, $dst_dir) {
                if(is_dir($dst_dir)){
                    return "Dir $dst_dir Already exists";
                } else {
                    $d = dir($src_dir);
                    ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dst_dir); //echo "creat dir $dst_dir";
                    while($file = $d->read()) { // do this for each file in the directory
                        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // to prevent an infinite loop
                            if (is_dir($src_dir."/".$file)) { // do the following if it is a directory
                            $src_dir_path=$src_dir."/".$file;
                            $dst_dir_path=$dst_dir."/".$file;

                            ftp_copyAll($conn_id, $src_dir_path, $dst_dir_path); // recursive part
                            } else {                        
                                $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file, $src_dir."/".$file, FTP_BINARY); // put the files
                                //echo "creat files::: ".$dst_dir."/".$file ."";
                                echo " ";
                            }
                        }
                        ob_flush() ;
                        flush(); 
                        usleep(90000);
                        //sleep(1);
                    }
                    $d->close();
                }
                 return true;
            }
```

Comment: We are using FTP_BINARY here for upload